# Eloquent relations, hasMany after a belongsTo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In the `User` model I am using `belongsTo` to find out which user's the `User` follows:

```
public function following()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'connections', 'user', 'follows');
}
```

While that is fine I also want to get item's from the table `Feed` which has `owner` set to the  value in the `follows` column of `connections` so i tried adding this function to the `User` model:

```
public function feed()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Feed', 'owner')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

and then calling everything with:

```
User::find(Auth::user()->id)->following->feed;
```

And this throws an error, I guess I can't call a `hasMany` after the `belongsTo`?

Comment: @JosephSilber sure it might be (idk), that's not what I'm looking for though. I need to be able to send an id of any user.

Answer (score 0):

`User::find(Auth::user()->id)` is equivalent to `Auth::user()`. Just use the latter.

---

Since `following` is a `belongsToMany` relationship, it returns multiple records. So `Auth::user()->following` returns a collection, not a model. You can only call your `feed` method on the model directly.

---

If you're using Laravel 4.1 (which is still in beta), there's a new `hasManyThrough` type relationship that you might be able to use here.

Comment: This doesnt give me an array of Feed item's from the users i follow does it?, That is what i need to get...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it via lazy loading?

```
User::with("following.feed")->first();
```

I can't say whether or not it will work but it might.